# How to enable Open "safe" files after downloading in Safari

Tags: terminal, safari

I have checked `Open "safe" files after downloading` as shown below in Safari. But it does not open the downloaded file. In the past, I might have touched some related options via Terminal, which I don't remember what it was.

How can I enable this option?

[image]

Comment: What filetype was the downloaded file?

Comment: I downloaded pdf files